# elasticbeanstalk environment creation from cloudfromation freezes

Tags: elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudformation

I am migrating my app to a cloudformation stack. When stack creation starts creating the elasticbeanstalk, environment creation freezes at:

```
2:08pm
Added instance [i-<myinstance>] to your environment.
2:07pm
Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
2:06pm
Created security group named:
sg-<mygroup>
2:06pm
Created EIP: <myip>
2:06pm
Environment health has transitioned to Pending. Initialization in progress (running for 11 seconds). There are no instances.
2:06pm
Using elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-<mybucket> as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2:06pm
createEnvironment is starting.
```

here is my stack template:
https://pastebin.com/awAmAg7w

here is a much simplified template based on aws sample elastic beanstalk template that also doesn't start
https://pastebin.com/0Xs2pL0f

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-ec2vpc

`AssociatePublicIpAddress` had to be set to `true`